# IE users can't fill out my search input field

Tags: jquery, css, html, navigation, bootstrap-4

I am currently building a site that often requires long search terms.
For this reason I chose to do a dropdown search bar as shown in the bootsnipp below, I have added some styling to it but the rest of the code is the same.

Unfortunately, IE won't allow users to enter any text into the search input field - it does show a cursor.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I might be able to add to the code specifically for IE?

I have put the link to the working example on Bootsnipp here it includes the HTML, CSS and JS. The example has the same problem as I am having.

[View menu with problem here + HTML, CSS & JS](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/a6aV0)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't IE specific, it is the padding that is pushing the text out of the input.Chrome just seems to ignore the padding.

```
.navbar-bootsnipp .bootsnipp-search .form-control {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 25px 0px;
}
```

Change the padding and add a height to the input

```
.navbar-bootsnipp .bootsnipp-search .form-control {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I found the issue by looking in the developer tools

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Hope this helps :)